# Breaking a line only when not doing so would cause an overfull \hbox

Tags: line-breaking, discretionary

In my thesis, I have a subsection title which generates an overfull \hbox in the body of the thesis, but not in the table of contents. So I would like to instruct TeX to break the line in the body, but not in the index. My try was:

```
\discretionary{\\}{}{}
```

and the response was:

[image]

So it doesn't work, and I'm starting to think I am misinterpreting `\discretionary`. Right now I am out of ideas. Is there a way to achieve the above?

PS Just hyphenating `spaces` won't do because it won't remove the overfull \hbox.

Comment: The macro `\allowbreak` is used to signify a permissible (but not mandatory) breakpoint.

Comment: @Steven That is surely a macro to keep in mind. 'Cause it just solved my problem :). Would you mind converting your comment to an answer?

Comment: the usual way is `\subsection[no break]{with\\break}` or actually headings are better set raggedright in which case you should not get an overfull box anyway. (You haven't supplied a test file so no tested answer)

Comment: @MickG the documented latex version of `\allowbreak` is `\linebreak[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `\allowbreak` provides a permissible, but not mandatory breakpoint (without hyphen). If one wants the breakpoint hyphenatable (also called an optional hyphenation), then `\-` should be used.

As one can see, the toc entries are all the same, even though the subsectioning title in the first case overfills the `\hbox`, in the second, breaks without hyphen, and in the third, breaks with hyphen.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{This is a testtesttest This is a testtesttest This tezzzzzzzz
  This is a testtesttest This is a testtesttest }

\subsection{This is a testtesttest This is a testtesttest This tezz\allowbreak zzzzzz 
  This is a testtesttest This is a testtesttest }

\subsection{This is a testtesttest This is a testtesttest This tezz\-zzzzzz 
  This is a testtesttest This is a testtesttest }

\end{document}
```

[image]